# Is it possible to pivot a table without using the pivot function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query that produces 2 columns: Month & Count

```
Month      COUNT
Jan 2018    563
Feb 2018    701
Mar 2018    682
Apr 2018    596
May 2018    395
Jun 2018    538
```

But the result I get is:

```
Jan 2018    Feb 2018    Mar 2018    Apr 2018    May 2018    Jun 2018
   563        701         682         596         395          538
```

Obviously, my query needs tweaking.

I tried using the pivot function but it is way too complicated so I was wondering if there is a different way to write the query to get the desired format.

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT

,SUM(CASE WHEN DateRequest BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-01-31' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Jan 2018'
,SUM(CASE WHEN DateRequest BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND '2018-02-28' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Feb 2018'
,SUM(CASE WHEN DateRequest BETWEEN '2018-03-01' AND '2018-03-31' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Mar 2018'
,SUM(CASE WHEN DateRequest BETWEEN '2018-04-01' AND '2018-04-30' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Apr 2018'
,SUM(CASE WHEN DateRequest BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-31' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'May 2018'
,SUM(CASE WHEN DateRequest BETWEEN '2018-06-01' AND '2018-06-30' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Jun 2018'

FROM RequestHeader
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: I don't think you want to pivot. I think you want to GROUP BY. We can help with that, but you'll have to tell us what database product you are using. It will be something like `SELECT month(daterequest), year(daterequest), count(*) FROM requestHeader WHERE daterequest BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-06-30' GROUP BY month(daterequest), year(daterequest);`. That `month()` and `year()` are psuedocode though that will be replaced with whatever date functionality your RDBMS has.

Comment: That works perfectly!  Thank you so much JNevil!  I'm using SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

Have a derived table where you extract the year and month parts. `GROUP BY` its result:

```
select m, y, count(*)
from
(
    select month(DateRequest) as m, year(DateRequest) as y
    from tablename
) dt
group by m, y
```

If your dbms doesn't support the `month()` and `year()` functions, try ANSI SQL's `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DateRequest)` and `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DateRequest)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your code suggests `SQL Server` syntax, so i would try with :

```
WITH CTE AS (
     <query>
)
SELECT CC.*
FROM CTE C CROSS APPLY
     ( VALUES ('Jan 2018', [Jan 2018]), 
              ('Feb 2018', [Feb 2018]),
                . . . 
     ) CC(mn, cnt);
```